# string to decimal number in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

What is the most transparent and elegant string to decimal number procedure you can create in Scheme?

It should produce correct results with "+42", "-6", "-.28", and "496.8128", among others.

This is inspired by the previously posted list to integer problem:  [how to convert a list to num in scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683479/how-to-convert-a-list-to-num-in-scheme)

I scragged my first attempt since it went ugly fast and realized others might like to play with it as well.

Comment: The problem is a bit ill-defined. Can you specify a grammar for the legal inputs?

Comment: Sure. I meant to imply that. There is an optional leading sign. There are optional digits, there is an optional decimal point, there are optional additional digits. There must be at least one digit. I'd prefer not to remove the fun parts of the journey by actually defining a grammer. Does this work for you? Extra credit for adding optional 'E' and one or more digits of exponent. Extra credit for allowing arbitrary bases. Oops, this isn't class, there is no extra credit in stack overflow.

Comment: BTW, this means that "" is not valid; I erroneously included it originally.

Comment: why not use the built-in `string->number`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much shorter, also makes the result inexact with a decimal point, and deal with any +- prefix.  The regexp thing is only used to assume a valid syntax later on.

```
#lang racket/base
(require racket/match)
(define (str->num s)
  ;; makes it possible to assume a correct format later
  (unless (regexp-match? #rx"^[+-]*[0-9]*([.][0-9]*)?$" s)
    (error 'str->num "bad input ~e" s))
  (define (num l a)
    (match l
      ['() a]
      [(cons #\. l) (+ a (/ (num l 0.0) (expt 10 (length l))))]
      [(cons c l) (num l (+ (* 10 a) (- (char->integer c) 48)))]))
  (define (sign l)
    (match l
      [(cons #\- l) (- (sign l))]
      [(cons #\+ l) (sign l)]
      [_ (num l 0)]))
  (sign (string->list s)))
```

Comment: Nice, I like the regex validation. I was shooting for a general scheme solution in the question as posed. I think making decimal numbers inexact is wrong, since they are well defined rational numbers.

Comment: One reason to make decimals inexact is that Scheme readers usually do that too.  In any case, there's one `0.0` in the code which you can change to `0` to have it always be exact.  As for the general scheme solution -- you did use a `racket` tag, so I used regexps and `match`; getting rid of the latter is very easy, and getting rid of the former is also not difficult by folding the error checking into the two loops.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a first shot. Not ugly, not beautiful, just longer than I'd like. Tuning another day. I will gladly pass the solution to someone's better creation.

```
((define (string->number S)
  (define (split L c) 
    (let f ((left '()) (right L))
      (cond ((or (not (list? L)) (empty? right)) (values L #f))
            ((eq? c (car right)) (values (reverse left) (cdr right)))
            (else (f (cons (car right) left) (cdr right))))))
  (define (mkint L) 
    (let f ((sum 0) (L (map (lambda (c) (- (char->integer c) (char->integer #\0))) L)))
      (if (empty? L) sum (f (+ (car L) (* 10 sum)) (cdr L)))))
  (define list->num
    (case-lambda
      ((L) (cond ((empty? L) 0) 
                 ((eq? (car L) #\+) (list->num 1 (cdr L))) 
                 ((eq? (car L) #\-) (list->num -1 (cdr L)))
                 (else (list->num 1 L))))
      ((S L) (let*-values (((num E) (split L #\E)) ((W F) (split num #\.)))
               (cond (E (* (list->num S num) (expt 10 (list->num E))))
                     (F (* S (+ (mkint W) (/ (mkint F) (expt 10 (length F))))))
                     (else (* S (mkint W))))))))
  (list->num (string->list S)))
```