# append numbers from list in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm currently learning scheme and I've come across an example problem.
taking a list as input turn each element into a digit of a number and the lists in backwards order. e.g.
(4 2 0 1) => 1024, (3 9 9) => 993 etc.

I have the basic construct already:

```
(define dlnat-to-nat
  (lambda (d)
    (cond
      ((null? d) 0)
      ((not (list? d)) (error "No list given in parameters" d))
      ((append (car d) (if (not (null? (cdr d)))
                           (dlnat-to-nat (cdr d))
                           '()))))))
```

I was trying to use (append) and that does not work in this case and I don't know of any alternative to append the digits as a number?

Comment: What's the desired output? a list pr a number?

Comment: a number. Input would be '(1 2 3 4) and the output is the number 4321.

Comment: This has already been answered in other questions, e.g., [how to convert a list to num in scheme?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1683479/1281433).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use list operations for building a number as output, `append` is for appending *lists*, not numbers. Use basic arithmetic operations instead:

```
(define dlnat-to-nat
  (lambda (d)
    (cond ((or (null? d) (not (list? d)))
           (error "Invalid input:" d))
          ((null? (cdr d))
           (car d))
          (else
           (+ (car d) (* 10 (dlnat-to-nat (cdr d))))))))
```

A more efficient solution would use tail recursion:

```
(define dlnat-to-nat
  (lambda (d)
    (if (or (null? d) (not (list? d)))
        (error "Invalid input:" d)
        (let loop ((lst (reverse d)) (acc 0))
          (if (null? lst)
              acc
              (loop (cdr lst) (+ (car lst) (* 10 acc))))))))
```

And a more idiomatic implementation would use higher-order procedures:

```
(define dlnat-to-nat
  (lambda (d)
    (if (or (null? d) (not (list? d)))
        (error "Invalid input:" d)
        (foldr (lambda (e acc) (+ e (* 10 acc))) 0 d))))
```

Pick the one that best suits your needs!